# Infinite series of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, absolute-convergence

Let S be the set of sequences whose series converge absolutely. We define 2 norms on S: $$\| \{ a_n \}_{n=0}^{ \infty } \|_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty | a_n |$$ and, $$\| \{ a_n \}_{n=0}^\infty \|_{\sup} = \sup \{ |a_n|_{n=0}^\infty \} $$
Note: S is the set of sequences such that $\| a \|_1 < \infty.$ (The sup-norm is sometimes called the infinity-norm.)

Define a linear operator $\Sigma : S \to \mathbb{R}$ by: $$\Sigma \big( \{ a_n \}_{n=0}^\infty \big) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$
Question 1: find the operator norm of $\Sigma$ using $\| . \|_1$.

Question 2: show that the operator norm of $\Sigma$ using $\| .\|_{\sup}$ is unbounded.

Can anyone help me answer this question or give me hints. Also sorry about my latex code I am new at it and very bad but I tried my best!

Comment: Good job for a first time LaTeX user!

Comment: Thanks! How did you make it so the equations don't change the line?

Comment: Just use one dollar signs instead of two.

Comment: Ahhh I see, Thank you friend :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINTS**:

$1)$ Prove an easy inequality of that norm and then find an example where the equality holds.

$2)$ Think harmonically :)

Comment: Tell me if there is something you want me to explain better.

Comment: Well I don't really understand what the question is asking of me, I understand what a norm is but I don't know what the operator norm is.

Comment: Then you should consult this first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions

Comment: Was just reading this page now haha! Thanks.

Comment: ok, so because $a_n \leq 1* \mid a_n \mid$ this means that $c \leq 1$?

Comment: Then by finding an example of a sequence where the operator and the norm are equal proves that the infimum of c is 1 and thus the operator norm is equal to 1, is that correct?

Comment: and for part 2 I simply need to show a single example of $c \to \infty$ since it must be true for all sequences and then I am done right?

Comment: Exactly for part $1)$. For part $2)$, you just want to show that the operator maps on of the sequences to $\infty$ (which is not the car for every sequence), therefore it is unbounded.

Comment: So just find any sequence in which the sum is unbounded and has a supremum that exists?

Comment: Yes. "Think harmonically" was a hint to try the harmonic series xD

Comment: Oh good thinking,, thanks for your help, you really helped me understand it rather than just giving me the answer, I appreciate that.

Comment: Hey I have a question it states in the question that it only applies to sequences whose series "converge absolutely", how can a series converge absolutely and be unbounded, I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: Like for sequences, being bounded is a necessary condition for convergence, so it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

$|\Sigma (a_n)=|\sum a_n|\leq \sum |a_n|$ so $\|\Sigma\| \leq 1$. Since $\Sigma (1,0,0,...)=1$ and $\|(1,0,0...0\|_1=1$ we see that $\|\Sigma\| \geq 1$. Hence $\|\Sigma\| = 1$.

Now $|\Sigma (1,\frac1 2 ,..\frac 1 N,0,0...)| \to \infty$ but $\| (1,\frac1 2 ,..\frac 1 N,0,0...)\|_{sup} \leq 1$ for all $N$ so $\Sigma$ is unbounded for the second norm.

Comment: My hints were not directed to you. They were for the OP to explore.

Comment: But the series of the second sequence you defined, $(1,\frac{1}{2},...)$ does not converge absolutely, in fact it diverges.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is bounded then there would be a constant $C $such that $|\Sigma (1,\frac1 2 ,..\frac 1 N,0,0...)|  \leq C \| (1,\frac1 2 ,..\frac 1 N,0,0...)\|_{sup}$ for every $N$. But this is a contradiction since RHS is bounded and LHS tends to $\infty$. @jacobbradley